# Centering form-inline form-group

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

An ASP.NET page form set to class "form-inline center"

The page Head has the following style:

```
<style>
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        .center { text-align: center; }
    }

  </style>
```

The page has a "form-group" as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:label ID="lblName" class="control-label" runat="server">Enter/Scan Equipment ID:</asp:label>
    <asp:textbox id="txtName" Width="150" MaxLength="15" Runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSubmit" Enabled="true" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

The above "form-group" is centered. But all other elements of the page are centered as well.  If I remove style .center (above), none of the elements are centered. How can I can remove the style .center but keep the "form-group" centered?

Answer (score 0):

If using bootstrap then try the answer

Try adding "text-center" class to form-group.

If you want the form to be centered in sm devices then create a form again and add class "visible-sm" and then add class "text-center". This helps in showing the form only for smaller devices and text-center helps center aligning.

```html
<div class="form-group visible-sm text-center">
    <asp:label ID="lblName" class="control-label" runat="server">Enter/Scan Equipment ID:</asp:label>
    <asp:textbox id="txtName" Width="150" MaxLength="15" Runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:textbox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnSubmit" Enabled="true" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: Pranita, yes, I am using Bootstrap 3. I added text-center to the class, as you suggested, but this didn't make a difference. The group shows on the left.  I even added style="text-align: center" to the <div> element but even that didn't center the controls in the form-group.  But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The solution is to add style "display: block" to the div of class "form-group"
Just thought I would share in case someone is wondering.